# Problemas com Append e slideToggle

Tags: jquery

Estou com um probleminha aqui que é o seguinte.
Eu tenho uma linha do tempo que exibe algumas postagens, por ajax eu carrego mais conteúdos e faço um append, os novos itens que são exibidos não pegam o slideToggle.
Eu adicionei manualmente novamente o script na página que está enviando o conteúdo por ajax e o slideToggle funciona, o problema é o seguinte, quando ele abre, ele já fecha rapidamente e não deixa a div em exibição, alguém sabe como faço para resolver ?
Já coloquei display none e não resolveu.

```
$("#maisPostagens").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#carregando").toggle();
    var posts = $(".postagens:last").attr("lang");
    if (posts) {
        var url = '_funControllers/exibePostagensLinhaDoTempo.php?posts=' + posts;
        setTimeout(function () {
            $.get(url, function (dataReturn) {
                $("#carregando").toggle();
                $(".auto").append(dataReturn);
            });
        }, 1000);

    }
});
```

---

```
//efeito de aparecer e esconder divs de Comentários

$(".auto .postagens .comentarios .linkComentario").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('.externa').find('.comentarioPost').slideToggle();

});
```

Obrigado

Comment: Provavelmente é a maneira que você está adicionando o evento aos elementos, ele deve adicionar quando a página é carregada a primeira vez a todos os elementos que existem nela, em seguida quando seu ajax executa e surgem novos elementos esses não possuem o evento. Pra arrumar ou você reexecuta a adição do evento após o ajax ser executado, ou muda a maneira que o evento é adicionado ao evento (tendo tempo de vida enquanto durar a página).

Comment: Obrigado Luiz, como eu faço para o código durar mesmo depois do append ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No evento `click` você pode fazer assim:

```
$(document).on("click", ".auto .postagens .comentarios .linkComentario", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('.externa').find('.comentarioPost').slideToggle();
});
```

Quando o elemento é criado dinamicamente, uma técnica muito boa é defini-lo após o evento, como no exemplo acima, e atribuir o evento ao `document` ou ao elemento "pai de todos".

### Exemplo sem a técnica

```js
$('button').click(function(){
$('body').append('<div class="box"></div>');
})

$('.box').on('click', function(){
 $(this).css('background', '#fff')
})
```

```css
.box{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>adicionar</button>
```

Repare que as divs são criadas dinamicamente, e o `click` não funciona.

### Exemplo com a técnica

```js
$('button').click(function(){
$('body').append('<div class="box"></div>');
})

$(document).on('click','.box', function(){
 $(this).css('background', 'red')
})
```

```css
.box{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>adicionar</button>
```

Repare que agora as dvis com o evento `click` reagem a ele.

Comment: Olá Samir, muito obrigado pela super dica =D

Funcionou perfeitamente.

Obrigado